# open file on windows with scala source.fromFile()

Tags: java, scala

I try to open a File on windows, but can't get it running.

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
>       at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source) [...]

What is the desired format here?

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile("pathString").getLines()) {
  println(line)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this often as an encoding issue. Either pass `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` to your java process or pass `"UTF-8"` or whatever your encoding is as the second parameter in `Source.fromFile`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did it `for (line <- Source.fromFile("C:\\path\\file.txt", "UTF-8").getLines()) {
      println(line)
    }`